# Visual studio doesn't recognize TextMeshProUGUI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to edit a TextMeshPro's text through script, but visual studio doesn't recognize TextMeshProUGUI, the closest thing it recognizes is TextMesh, but it doesn't work.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you see this `Unity` forum post? https://forum.unity.com/threads/the-type-or-namespace-name-textmeshprougui-could-not-be-found.544102/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it's this:

```
using TMPro;
```

Then I can use

```
public TextMeshProUGUI textMesh;
```

in a class just fine